# dates calculation in bash

Tags: shell, unix, date

I have a file full of dates with this format (2002-09-26 02:20:30),
I want to extract the last 5 days from the end of the file , here is what I wrote

```
 END-DATE=tail -1 my file (which is 2002-09-26 02:20:30)
 time=$(expr 60 * 60 * 24 * 5) ( counting 5days which is 432000) 
 up to know every thing is ok ! the problem is with next line, 
 START-DATE=`expr END-DATE - time`
```

seems it's wrong : `expr: non-numeric argument`

how should I convert this time to epoch time ?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: can you please your problem , with some examples...

Comment: we want to see the code you have tried, not the psuedo-code you have thought of, `END-DATE=tail -1 myFile` will never work. Have you tried searching here on S.O. with '[bash] date arithmetic' and similar, there are already numerous answers that will help answering your question available.  (This is your 4th question about essentially the same problem. You're going to have to spend some time learning how shell scripts work OR how to write a question that people can respond to). Good luck.

Comment: is the file sorted?  i.e. are the last 5 days within the last `N` lines?

Answer (score 1):

`EDATE` is not defined, maybe you made a typo and it should be `END-DATE`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the variable, EDATE vs $EDATE (did you really mean END-DATE ?)

```
START_DATE=`expr $EDATE - time`
```

(Note that you cannot have a - in shell variable names, so START-DATE and END-DATE are invalid. Name them START_DATE and END_DATE rather)

Comment: I wrote END-DATE here so everybody understand I want to subtract 5 days from the last date of the file, the problem is not this , I dont know how to work with dates basically

Comment: @ayda Ok, but the answers here answers your original question, and corrects the wrong shell code. What are you actually asking ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the date 5 days before a given timestamp and have GNU Coreutils installed, you could use `date -d "$(tail -n 1 some/file.ext) 5 days ago"`; if you want that in a particular format, try looking at the man page `date(1)` (that is, enter `man 1 date`).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a bunch of tools ([dateutils](https://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils)) to tackle exactly these kinds of problems, in particular `dgrep` might help:

Off the cuff, I'd go for

```
EDATE=$(tail -n1 MY_FILE)
THRES=$(dadd "${EDATE}" -5d)
dgrep ">=${THRES}" < MY_FILE
```